# How do I get ActionMailer to log sent messages but NOT include the attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I like that Rails automatically logs all messages that are sent out from the app. What I **don't** like is how it fills up my log file with huge blocks of useless Base64-encoded text. This makes looking through the log file a pain because I have to skip past these megabytes-long blocks of unreadable noise. It also causes the log file to grow too quickly and fill up the disk.

How can I get it to still log all messages that are sent but **NOT include any of the attachments**? Is there a way to tell it to strip out the attachments before logging or something?

Usually all I'm interested in seeing are the headers (subject, who it was sent to) and (at least some of the time) the message body text.

It wouldn't hurt to also have a *list* of the attachments (file name and type) too — but it certainly does me no good to see the full Base64 dump of all the attachments! (If I want to check and see if the attachments are coming through okay, I already know how to add a mail interceptor that bcc's all outgoing mail to my inbox.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having it log the following details about each mail that gets sent out:

1. The headers
2. The structure of the email (which parts are within which other parts), including a list of attachments, before stripping out all
   attachments
3. Decoded, human-readable, searchable message bodies (the Rails default is to log the *encoded*, which is hard for a human to read
   and breaks words in random places, making it hard to search)

To accomplish this, I overrode [`ActionMailer::Base.set_payload_for_mail`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L557) in my app and replaced [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L557):

```
payload[:mail]       = mail.encoded
```

with a version that:

1. Creates a copy of the Mail object
2. Calls `mail.without_attachments!`, and
3. Only logs:

   1. `mail.header.encoded`
   2. the output from `mail.inspect_structure` (from [my fork](https://github.com/TylerRick/mail))
   3. the result of calling `part.decoded` for each (non-attachment) part.

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/TylerRick/ec2d033766fd14f2afd6) for the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Logging of the message body is handled here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/log_subscriber.rb#L14

```
module ActionMailer
  class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
    def deliver(event)
      info do
        recipients = Array(event.payload[:to]).join(', ')
        "\nSent mail to #{recipients} (#{event.duration.round(1)}ms)"
      end

      debug { event.payload[:mail] }
    end
    # ... more methods ...
  end
end
```

If you want to exclude the mail body entirely you can change the log level to exclude 'debug'.  Otherwise you're only option is to override this method and do your own thing.

Unfortunately `event.payload[:mail]` is a String.  Removing attachments could be messy. Showing just the headers wouldn't be that hard with a regex.  Otherwise you'd need to recreate the Mail object from that string and extract what you want.

Another option would be to change the logger used by ActionMailer so that it logs to it's own file.  That would at least keep your standard Rails log clean.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb#L12

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Lots of good suggestions! I guess showing just the headers using a Regexp wouldn't be *too* bad... though I'm going to try a bit more to get it to include the text and html bodies too. Ack, too bad `event.payload[:mail]` is a String. If I'm going to be overriding a method anyway, would it be any worse, I wonder, to just override the method that *adds* the payload (`ActionMailer::Base.set_payload_for_mail`)? Looking into this now and will post my solution if I get it working...